# I am trying to link a selection made in a javascript or HTML code and link it to a PHP variable. How would I go about doing this?

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables, menu

I am trying to set it up so that when I would click a certain link on a dropdown menu, it would link to a PHP variable and refresh the page with the new content.

Basically when I click the link, it would already have a certain variable attached to it and when clicked it would send the variable to a link/string of PHP code that would bring new content into the page.

Example if "Choice 1" is clicked **option** in the code below would be changed to Choice 1.

```
SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE choice="option"
```

Comment: I don't know if you are asking about `$_GET` or AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

call your links like this:

```
<a href="/folder/?var1=some_value">link</a>
```

then, in PHP, get it:

```
$var = $_GET['var1'] // $var1 = 'some_value' now
```

everything after '?' in link goes into global array $_GET in php. Separate variables by '&':

```
<a href="/folder/?var1=some_value&var2=some_other_value">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.xajax.net/ for PHP